# about using lapply to replace the for loop

Tags: r

```
for ( i in 1:12){
    if ( i ==1 ){
      unique_optionid = unique(brioption[which(brioption$volume <=0 & brioption$date == last_days[i]),]$optionid)
      brioption1 = brioption[which(!brioption$optionid %in% unique_optionid),]
    } else {
      unique_optionid = unique(brioption[which(brioption$volume <=0 & brioption$date == last_days[i]),]$optionid)
      brioption1 = rbind(brioption1,brioption[which(!brioption$optionid %in% unique_optionid),])
    }
  }
```

Here is the sample for brioption:

> structure(list(secid = c(5005, 5005, 5005, 5005, 5005, 5005,  5005,
> 5005, 5005, 5005), optionid = c(10224753, 10002894, 10071876,
> 10323301, 10467477, 10547385, 10640778, 10582298, 10535793, 10692099
> ), date = structure(c(9499, 9499, 9499, 9499, 9499, 9499, 9499,  9499,
> 9499, 9499), class = "Date"),
> volume = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),

please help me to write it as the lapply one

make it more efficient, thank you!

Comment: Please provide sample input, desired output, and a description of what your code is doing in words.

Comment: The nicest way to share sample data is with `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable and includes class and structure information. Use `dput(brioption[1:10, ])` to share the first 10 rows of `brioption` - choose a suitable small subset to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I've uploaded the sample data, last_days is a list contain the date data ( the end of each month, so it's there is 12 elements in last_days.

Comment: The purpose of it is, for the end of each month, I want to keep to rows that the volume should be positive, and use the rbind to collect the data I want

Comment: Your sample data isn't complete - but if you just want to select rows with volume > 0 with dplyr you can do `as_tibble(brioption1) |> filter(volume > 0)`